# Trying to display items from a class based on input from user

Tags: c#, winforms

Follow up I'm re adding sections of this code as I go along as such it allows me to work and identify errors in blocks which is much simpler than looking at the whole thing. Trying to get the function to execute on the `enter_click` display 2 doesn't show and it freezes. So one display `menu` shows a menu from the class `Items`, the `Disp` is integrated with the keypad in that it just shows the numbers/buttons pressed. The secondary display `Disp2` should display the item name based on the button press(what's[image] shown in the TextBox) Using MVS 2010
Here's the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Items> STOCK = new List<Items>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            this.STOCK = new List<Items>
           {
            new Items{ id = 1, Name = "Bun", Price = 100},
            new Items{ id = 2, Name = "Soda", Price = 80},
            new Items{ id = 3, Name = "Cheese", Price =70},
            new Items{ id = 4, Name = "Tissue", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 5, Name = "Fabuloso", Price = 140},
            new Items{ id = 6, Name = "Grace Mackerel", Price = 90},
            new Items{ id = 7, Name = "Rice", Price = 50},
            new Items{ id = 8, Name = "Flour", Price = 40},
            new Items{ id = 9, Name = "Sugar", Price = 30},
           };
        }

        public class Items
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public decimal Price { get; set; }
        }

        private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            STOCK.ForEach(x => strBuilder.Append(string.Format("ID {0} - Name: {1} Price: {2:C2}", x.id, x.Name, x.Price)));
            menu.Text = menu.Text + strBuilder.ToString();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button B = (Button)sender;
            Disp.Text = Disp.Text + B.Text;
        }


        private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         do
            {
                var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(i => i.id);

                var selecteditems = new List<Items>();
                if (Disp.Text == "00")
                {
                    break;
                }
                int id;
                if (!int.TryParse(Disp.Text, out id))
                {
                    Disp2.Text = ("Enter number or '00' ");
                    continue;
                }
                if (STOCKDict.ContainsKey(id))
                {
                    var item = STOCKDict[id];
                    selecteditems.Add(item);
                    Disp2.Text = (item.Name);
                }
                else
                {
                    Disp2.Text = (id + " is not available");
                }
            } while (true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is inside your do {}while(true) loop, especially the following piece:

```
if (!int.TryParse(Disp.Text, out id))
{
    Disp2.Text = ("Enter number or '00' ");
    continue;
}
```

In your loop you check the following condition:

```
int.TryParse(Disp.Text, out id)
```

But inside your loop this condition never changes(Disp.Text is always the same) and therefore there is at least one possible case where the loop never stops.

You could replace 'continue' with 'break':

```
if (!int.TryParse(Disp.Text, out id))
{
    Disp2.Text = ("Enter number or '00' ");
    break;
}
```

I am not exactly sure what actually you try to accomplish but it seems you should also replace:

```
{
    Disp2.Text = (id + " is not available");
}
```

with:

```
{
    Disp2.Text = (id + " is not available");
    break;
}
```

However, as Disp.Text doesn't change and STOCKDict can have only one entry with a unique key the do/while loop isn't necessary at all and the following code would do the job without running into a never ending loop:

```
List<Items>() selecteditems = new List<Items>();

private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var STOCKDict = STOCK.ToDictionary(x => x.id);
    int id;
    if (!int.TryParse(Disp.Text, out id))
    {
        Disp2.Text = ("Enter number or '00' ");
    }
    else
    {
        if (STOCKDict.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            var item = STOCKDict[id];
            selecteditems.Add(item);
            Disp2.Text = (item.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Disp2.Text = (id + " is not available");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that; changed it but still froze. I'm more concerned with getting the secondary display `Disp2` to show

Comment: @Whitti1. Please check my updated answer. Probably the remaining condition 'if (STOCKDict.ContainsKey(id))' could end with a break as well.But this would mean that no do-while loop is required at all. It is not clear what you actually try to accomplish within the method.

Comment: It was originally a console program; we were instructed to use the same code and apply it in windows form. The menu is based on the class which was initialized at the top. In console when the user input 1 for example it would show that Bun was added to a list which was then summed up and used to give a subtotal for calculation. So the menu is displayed the keypad would serve to drive user input. What I'm trying to accomplish is for the secondary display to Show the item the number in the text box matches; ideally it should do this after pressing enter button

Comment: Ok, it is clearer now. Check my updated answer. It just checks if your STOCK list contains an item with a specific id (Disp.Text) and adds the item to a list. In case there is no such item or the entered number is not an int, Disp2.Text shows a corresponding message.